# what does /= operation mean in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3

What does the operator /= mean in action script? I have seen some easing functions using this:

```
var ts:Number=(t/=d)*t;
```

but have no clue what this t/=d mean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo /= bar` is a shorthand form of `foo = foo / bar`.

The return value from the `foo /= bar` operation is `foo / bar`

The expanded form of this code is:

```
var ts:Number = t;
ts = ts / d;
ts = ts * ts;
t = t / d;
```

A better way of writing that line would have been:

```
t /= d;
var ts:Number = t * t;
```

Comment: Just one thing. I think you made a type in your code. The first chunk of code doesn't modify t. But the sencond (the "A better way" one) modifies it. Please fix it.

Comment: @Notbad, the first chunk was just to describe what was going on in setting the value of `ts`, but I've corrected it to show `t` being modified as well.

Answer (score 1):

That's the [division assignment](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#division_assignment) operator.

It's the same as saying

```
var ts:Number=(t=t/d)*t;
```

And since the code inside the parentheses is evaluated first, I believe the equivalent code is

```
t = t / d;
var ts:Number = t * t;
```

It is assigning `ts` and **modifying** the value of `t` in one line.

Comment: So the above code is the same that; vart tempT=t; t=t/d; var ts:Number=t*TempT? Sorry for the dumb question but the asignment in this place is killing me :)

Comment: I added further explanation. It sounds like it is calculating `t` squared, but `t` is divided by `d` beforehand. Note that the value of `t` is modified after this line.

Comment: You're welcome! I had a feeling that this is part of an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as `+=`, `*=`, `-=`, etc.

It divides the number by the number specified. It's shorthand code instead of doing

```
number = number / otherNumber;
```

Note that the code you posted will not work because it's setting the t variable, not returning what's left after dividing.

Comment: It should work. The code is just trying to do many things at once. In the end, it will return `t * t`. The catch is, `t` is divided by `d` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Like in other languages:

```
variable /= operand;
```

is shortcut for

```
variable = variable / operand;
```